# Какой самоучитель выбрать?

Tags: c++

Требуется выучить С++ в максимально короткие сроки параллельно с учебой в вузе. Посоветуйте какой-нибудь годный самоучитель. С меня нефть :3

Comment: для начала определиться с целью - просто что бы сдать экзамен или что бы устроиться на работу.
второе -  сроки, месяц, год, 5 лет.

Comment: Учил паскаль/делфи три года, обидно что не си. Нужен пока что только для учебы, а именно: хотелось бы самое наглядное пособие по синтаксису и семантике. Срок - месяц.

Comment: если паскаль-делфи знаем хорошо, то С выучить за месяц можно, с++  в базовом виде можно (уровень хелловорлдов)

Comment: Мне пожалуйста 1000 галлонов. Смените вуз на технический там где учат C++. Это самый лучший самоучитель.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я когда-то учил С++ по книге Стефана Р. Девиса, называлась С++ для чайников))
ISBN 5-8459-0160-X

Answer (score 2):

Харви М. Дейтел, Пол Дж. Дейтел Как программировать на C++ (2008). очень ясно и подробно. Лучше я ее не видал. Это мое личное мнение, так что прошу не очень пинать, если кому-то нравиться другая

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, никакой самоучитель не будет за вас учить, семантика слова "самоучитель" состоит в том, что он лишь помогает вам, остальное лишь дело вашего характера, способностей, умений принимать новое. А если по принципу: "Он хотел, лишь не хотя" - то таких самоучителей нет, не было и не будет. За срок в один месяц выучить плюсы нереально, Страуструп тоже его весь не знает.

Comment: >Нужен пока что только для учебы
>только для учебы
Зачем же мне весь, я спросил именно про синтаксис, именно синтаксис.
upd: как-то странно отображается.

Comment: если,для учебы,то мне нравится  Бьярн Страуструп"Программирование. Принципы и практика использования C++"издательства Вильямс,сам купил себе,толково и понятно написано

Comment: Спасибо, приобрету, посмотрю.

Answer (score 0):

Точно не помню, у издательства О Рейли была карманная книжка, где в сжатом виде очень подробно описан синтаксис языка (без конкретных IDE) и ничего лишнего. Для новичка тяжеловато будет по нему изучать, хотя сам по нему учил, а для уже знающего - очень хороший справочник. Если книжку найду, напишу подробнее название и авторов.

Comment: C++ Карманный справочник /К. Лоудон СПб. Питер, 2004 - 220 с.  
ISBN 5-94723-778-4

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего Книга братьев Дейтелов, оно входит в курс обучения в виндоусе (бесплатное обучение учеников, там проходят этим)...

Answer (score 0):

попробуй учебник липпмана "С++ для начинающих")))))